# What does the Fire Hydrant do?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In "Animal Crossing New Leaf," I see that one of the suggested public works projects was a fire hydrant. If I decide to put that public project up for donations, what will it do? Will there be a fire in my town?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many other Public Works Projects, the fire hydrant is **just for decoration**. As with the other decorative PWPs, the only real game mechanical effect it will have is that your **villagers will talk about it** when close to it.

Comment: oooooohh. Thanks. I would've had like 40 other questions about the public works projects. XD

Comment: What does PWP mean?

Comment: @JerryRox It stands for Public Works Project. Your PWPs count toward the perfect town status, among other things.